# How to downgrade to Stock Rom [HTC One X 3.20.401.1 CID HTC_203)

Tags: root-access, htc-one-x, stock-android, downgrade

I have a rooted HTC One X with JB 4.1.1 (3.20.401.1), I deleted some unnecessary softwares but still using stock ROM.

Yesterday I relocked the bootloader and tried to install original stock rom by using 3.14.x.x RUU file. But it gave me "Bootloader version error".So I'm stuck. I have no Nandroid backup for my CID :( I could not find the 3.20.401.1 RUU file nor related Nandroid backup anywhere on the internet.

Does someone has any suggestions? I would like to revert to Stock rom to be able to get official Sense 5 OTA update which will be released very soon by HTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, someone from XDA shared his Nandroid backup for Stock Rom, here is the link ;

http://docs.google.com/file/d/0B06FIZEUKDcHUlBVZFZPREtOS0k/edit?usp=sharing

The Original Thread on XDA : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=c89f980ba9f35f7e5ec9ae6b6bf11bef&t=1975140&page=139

Answer (score 1):

This guide is marked as "noob-friendly". Haven't tried it myself as I try to stay far away as I can from Sense:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1859714

You were looking for 3.20.401.1? Here you can find the Nandroid Backups:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1975140

Comment: I've already checked XDA, that's why I'm asking the question in this Q&A site. CID HTC_203 is listed as "MISSING" on #XDA...

MISSING CIDs : 
HTC__203
HTC__A07
HTC__304
HTC__016
T-MOB102
HTC_011
ORANG309
H3G__G04

Comment: As this wasn't clear in your initial question, I can only suggest asking help on XDA to see if someone is kind enough to provide you with a RUU or Nandroid backup for your CID. Good luck.

Comment: yep, I already got nandroid file from somebody on xda...